# Test for difference between groups with multiple variables

Tags: regression

Apologies for the horrible title, I'm not sure of the correct terminology. I'm working in R and have provided R code to show what I've tried, but this is a stats question, not a R question.

I have measurements (counts) of several variables for two groups. Something like this:

```
df <- tribble(
  ~'zone', ~'var1', ~'var2', ~'var3',
  'A', 5, 2, 6,
  'B', 1, 8, 0
)

df

  zone  var1 var2 var3
  A     5     2      6
  B     1     8      0
```

I've been testing for a difference (any difference) between the groups using a chi-squared test, like so:

```
chisq.test(df[ , 2:4])
```

This produces a significant result, so apparently the groups are different. But I would like to know *how* they are different. Which variable is driving the difference, and how? I could run a t-test for each individual variable, but that seems very cumbersome. I could also run an ANOVA (I think?), but I wasn't sure if that was appropriate for counts and I haven't seen a lot of examples similar to mine.

I would love to be able to make a statement like, "I found no significant difference in var2 between zones A and B, but var3 was significantly higher in zone A than zone B," or, "I found a difference in vars between zone A and B, which was driven largely by var1 being much higher in A." What is the appropriate test to use in this situation?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I believe if you follow that with R code `chisq.test(df[ , 2:4])$resi` and you'll get 'Pearson residuals` , sum of squares of which give chi-sq statistic. Residuals with largest absolute values contributed most to significant statistic, so _ad hoc_ comparisons of cells with such residuals sometimes helps with the kind of insight you're looking for. Often desired _ad hoc_ tests can be made by picking appropriate sub-tables of the $2\times 3$ table for the original chi-sq test.// Also, it seems you have small counts, so you might get more accurate P-val by using parameter `sim=T` in orig'l test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment continued to illustrate with R code:

Warning message with just `chisq.test(TAB)` prompted
me to try simulation (with argument `sim=T`).

```
TAB = rbind(c(5,2,6), c(1,8,0))
chisq.test(TAB, sim=T)$p.val
[1] 0.005497251
```

Significant below 1%. What's important?
Residuals in columns 2 and 3 look interesting.

```
chisq.test(TAB, sim=T)$resi
[1,]  0.7724873 -1.608109  1.303572
[2,] -0.9284142  1.932706 -1.566699
```

*Ad hoc* test on columns 2 and 3 of `TAB` gives
highly significant result. Is there a rewarding
interpretation of this?

```
chisq.test(TAB[,2:3], sim=T)$p.val
[1] 0.006496752
```

Comment: Thanks for getting me on the right track! I wound up running a post-hoc analysis with a bonferroni adjustment. I found [this](https://alanarnholt.github.io/PDS-Bookdown2/post-hoc-tests-1.html) page very helpful for explaining how and why to run it. For anyone else using R, I used `chisq.posthoc.test::chisq.post.test(data, simulate.p.value=TRUE)` and it worked great.